# Arquillian integration tests fails with UnsatisfiedResolutionException

Tags: integration-testing, dbunit, jboss-arquillian

I'm attempting to write some integration tests of an EJB interface using Arquillian, but for some reason I get an error saying that It cannot find the qualifiers for some of the injection points.(arbitrary which one per time I run the tests) I use dbunit to setup a hsqldb, within a junit rule.

```
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [no.driw.kraft.ejb.uttrans.mapping.DepartureMapper] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
```

In my `Pom` I have the following:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

In the test class I have this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@CreateSchema("sql/transportationplanCreateTables.sql")
public class TransportationplanManagerBeanDbIT {

    @Rule//junit rule for setting up persistence, creating schema and inserting dataset using dbunit
    public PersistenceUnitRule rule = new PersistenceUnitRule();
    @Inject//the ejb to be tested.
    private TransportationplanManager instance;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() throws Exception {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "driwkraft-ejb-integration-tests.war")
            .addPackages(true, TransportationplanManagerBean.class.getPackage())
            .addClasses(PersistenceHandler.class, JtaPersistenceProducer.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"))
            .addAsManifestResource("persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");
    }

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet("/data/integration/uttrans/transportationplan/validData_dbInput.xml")
    public void getDepartures_givenValidDataset_expectsCorrectResult() {
        .....
    }
}
```

All the classes that it complains that it does not find, is placed in a subpackage of the package sent in to the `WebArchive.addPackages` call above. `persistence.xml` are placed under `src/test/resources` along with an `arquillian.xml` file.

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="tomee-embedded" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
            <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
            <property name="dir">target/tomee-embedded</property>
            <property name="appWorkingDir">target/arquillian-embedded-working-dir</property>
            <property name="portRange">20001-30000</property>
            <property name="properties">
                dapsysReader = new://Resource?type=DataSource
                dapsysReader.JdbcDriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
                dapsysReader.JdbcUrl = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db
                dapsysReader.JtaManaged = true
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```